# Having been working on a branch, how can I merge into the trunk just a part of the files I've changed?

Tags: svn, version-control

I've just created a branch from our trunk. I've noticed there are a couple of files that don't compile against my Java Compiler (strangely, it does compile against my mates Java compiler). I've deleted them in my branch while they try to make the trunk's files conform to my compiler's stricter policy.

I've made a couple of changes in my branch and now I'd like to merge them into the trunk (the trunk is at the moment just as it was before I've made my branch). The problem is that I don't want that couple of deleted tests to leak into the trunk.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deleted action must have benn in a revision(s) right? You can merge a range of revisions using the `-r` switch and make sure that the revisions where you delete the part that you don't want in trunk.

If you are using a tool like TortoiseSVN, it is much more simpler. You can pick the revisions that you want to merge and hence ignore the ones in which you made those changes.

If you are including the deleting revision in merge anyway, you need not worry about the changed leaking into trunk. Also, you have to commit it after the merge, make sure these changes are not present in the changeset.

Comment: Hmm it's not so easy. The changes are spanned over several revisions. Nothing to do about this than to cherry pick them one by one, right?